# Login check with Basic Auth instead of plain text body

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I just checked the Getting Started guide on `LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle` and appears you can only use a POST request with username and password in plain-text JSON to [obtain a token](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#1-obtain-the-token).

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/api/login_check -d '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'
```

Is there another way to do this? For example by using Basic Authentication.
This way, the credentials aren't human readable and which would be safer for testing/logging/etc.

Lots of test tools provide Basic Auth integration, which is useful when sharing tests. It becomes a lot harder to hide this sensitive data when these have to be provided as a JSON request body.

Comment: Always use SSL. I wonder why base64-encoded username and password are safer.

Comment: Safer is not the best way to put it. I just want to avoid somebody reading my password 'by accident'.